# Parameter passed from callee but comes as null in the method definition

Tags: java, android, oop

I am basically trying to create an unzip function. I called the function with parameters in the block below:

```
UnzipUtility unzipUtility = new UnzipUtility();
    try {
        unzipUtility.unzip(localFilePath, parentPath);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Definition of the method is in a class UnzipUtility, the code as follows:

```
    public void unzip(String zipFilePath, String destDirectory) throws IOException {
    File destDir = new File(destDirectory);
    if (!destDir.exists()) {
        destDir.mkdir();
    }
    ZipInputStream zipIn = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFilePath));
    ZipEntry entry = zipIn.getNextEntry();
    // iterates over entries in the zip file
    while (entry != null) {
        String filePath = destDirectory + File.separator + entry.getName();
        if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
            // if the entry is a file, extracts it
            extractFile(zipIn, filePath);
        } else {
            // if the entry is a directory, make the directory
            File dir = new File(filePath);
            dir.mkdir();
        }
        zipIn.closeEntry();
        entry = zipIn.getNextEntry();
    }
    zipIn.close();
}
```

But during runtime, though parameters are passed properly in the main class, the values shows up as null in the unzip method.

Please help with this

The main class is as follows:

```
package com.example.sftpconnection;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
import com.jcraft.jsch.SftpException;


//import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
//import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
//import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.List;
import com.example.sftpconnection.UnzipUtility;

public class SFTPActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String fileName = "1234.zip";
    private String localFilePath;
    private String parentPath;
    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sftp);


        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>>() {
            @Override
            protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    Downloader(fileName);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

        }.execute();

        UnzipUtility unzipUtility = new UnzipUtility();
        try {
            unzipUtility.unzip(localFilePath, parentPath);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void Downloader(String fileName) {

        String user = "1234";
        String pass = "1234";
        String host = "1234";
        int portNum = 22;

        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session;

        try {

            session = jsch.getSession(user,host,portNum);
            session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setPassword(pass);
            session.connect();

            Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
            channel.connect();
            ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;


            File localFile = File.createTempFile("1234",".zip");
            sftpChannel.get(fileName,localFile.getAbsolutePath());
            //sftpChannel.get(fileName);

            Log.d(fileName, " has been downloaded");

            sftpChannel.exit();
            session.disconnect();
            localFilePath = localFile.getAbsolutePath();
            parentPath = localFile.getParent();
        } catch (JSchException | IOException | SftpException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

I edited the data fields for security reasons.

Comment: where you get null ?

Comment: post the error log

Comment: Could you please show the main class?

Comment: what you say is not possible. You for sure are passing something wrong. Try debugging.

Comment: @sasikumar I got the null values in the unzip method definition, during debugging.

Comment: @SanjeevSaha I have edited the question to include the main class.

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal Here's the variable values: destDirectory = null
destDirectory = null
this = {UnzipUtility@5439} 
zipFilePath = null
destDirectory = null

Comment: @SanchitaDas Could you please change your code as per my answer and see if it works for you or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could cut the following lines:

```
UnzipUtility unzipUtility = new UnzipUtility();
try {
    unzipUtility.unzip(localFilePath, parentPath);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

paste just below the following line in class **SFTPActivity**:

```
Downloader(fileName);
```

of method `doInBackground`. 
Actually the method `doInBackground()` runs in different thread from the thread in which the method `onCreate` runs. You attempt to use the variables before the method `Downloader(fileName)` could do its job. This is the reason why you see null values in variables like: `localFilePath` and `parentPath`

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked! :) Thanks for explaining too.

Comment: I would have loved to upvote, but i donot have enough reputation! :( Sorry. Is there any other way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your code does not work is because at the time of running this line:

```
unzipUtility.unzip(localFilePath, parentPath);
```

the variables `localFilePath` and `parentPath` have not been set.

You might argue that they *are* set in the method `Downloader`, which is called before the `unzip` line. Unfortunately, this is not true. In this case, code execution is not linear because you are using an `AsyncTask`. The stuff in the async task runs simultaneously with the lines that come after it.

Your download call is not going to finish before `unzipUtility.unzip` is called, because downloading takes a huge amount of time, compared to creating a new `UnzipUtility` object.

This is why `localFilePath` and `parentPath` are null.

One way to solve this problem is to move the unzip logic into the async task as well:

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>>() {
    @Override
    protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Downloader(fileName);

            UnzipUtility unzipUtility = new UnzipUtility();
            unzipUtility.unzip(localFilePath, parentPath);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}.execute();
```

Another way is to override `onPostExecute` in the `AsyncTask` as well:

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>>() {
     // doInBackground goes here...

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         try {
            UnzipUtility unzipUtility = new UnzipUtility();
            unzipUtility.unzip(localFilePath, parentPath);
         } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Okay. Thanks for detailed explanation. Will keep these points in mind next times.